# OnActionExecuted method cant be overriden in .NetCore 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In a test app I had been using to test various items in the past, I had a base controller.

BaseController (MVC5)

```
    public abstract class BaseController : Controller
    {
        protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            if (User != null)
            {
                var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
                var username = User.Identity.Name;
                var iconSource = ServicesAppSettings.UserIcons.FemaleUserIconSource;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
                {
                    var user = context.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        var gender = user.GetUserGender(username);
                        if (gender == DomainClasses.Enums.Gender.Male)
                        {
                            iconSource = ServicesAppSettings.UserIcons.MaleUserIconSource;
                        }
                        var fullName = user.GetFullName(username);
                        ViewData.Add("FullName", fullName);
                        ViewData.Add("IconSource", iconSource);
                    }
                }
            }
            base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        }       
    }
```

I am now building a Core 2.0 web template for myself and was trying to implement the base controller in Core 2.0 but the method is erring.

BaseController(MVC 6, .Net core 2.0)

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (User != null)
        {
            var baseArgs = new[] { "TestApp" };
            var context = ApplicationDbContextFactory.CreateDbContext(baseArgs);
            var username = User.Identity.Name;
            var iconSource = _config.GetSection("FemaleUserIcon");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
            {
                var user = context.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    var gender = user.GetUserGender(username);
                    if (gender == Gender.Male)
                    {
                        iconSource = _config.GetSection("MaleUserIcon");
                    }
                    var fullName = user.GetFullName(username);
                    ViewData.Add("FullName", fullName);
                    ViewData.Add("IconSource", iconSource);
                }
            }
        }
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
```

And the error message has to do with the method being protected

> 'BaseController.OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext)': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'public' inherited member

This worked perfectly fine in MVC 5, now using MVC 6 and .Net Core 2, this is failing. Any idea why this method can't be protected or private in this scenario? I don't see why it needs to be public.

Additionally, now that I am re-looking at this code, this is retrieving the user every time a controller action is called, isn't it? There has to be a better way to store this info the first time a user logs in. SqlDistributedCache?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The access modifier for the method in the base `Controller` class is `public` rather than `protected`:

```
public virtual void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context);
```

You can see this in the official source code too [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Controller.cs#L327).

The compiler error is telling you you can't change that in your inherited class. So you just need to change yours to match.

Comment: @DavidG...thanks, I got that, my question was really WHY was that changed? In MVC5 I was able to make that method protected

Comment: To figure out why, you'd have to ask Microsoft. The code history shows it's been this way since the first commit.

Comment: LOL...true that

Comment: This method must be overridden with the public access right ever since "ASP.NET Core for MVC" version which is current for ".NET MVC" currently. There have been many versions... :P and now after saying everything will become .NET Core, they will kill off .NET Core, so this might change again.